# Where is the Cell Hallway Key?

Tags: dishonored

There's an actionable door right outside Corvo's cell, but the key wasn't on any of the guards and it wasn't vital to the mission. How can I enter this room? Is it an Easter egg or something? What's inside?

[image: Cell Hallway]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you progress through the prison, you will eventually make it to the room on the other side of the gate.  You can open it from that side.  There is no key (AFAIK) that you can find, pick or loot from guards to unlock it from that side.

[image: from the other side]

You'll make it there through normal progression so don't worry about trying to open it.

Comment: I feel like many Bethesda games feature doors like that.

Answer (score 0):

When the objective to cross the yard comes up, if you go back to the door near Corvo's cell it becomes unlocked, and you can bypass the few guards in the yard across from the interrogation room.